# Regex to find 2 the same chars at the end of a string

Tags: regex, string

I have to find a regex with following rules.

- contains 8 to 20 chars (capital or normal).
- contains no whitespace chars.
- can't start with a number(0-9) or underscore (_).
- at the end of the string it hase to be 2 of the same char.
- must contain at least 1 number.

**OK:**

```
+234567899
a_1de*Gg
xy1Me*__
!41deF_hij2lMnopq3ss
C234567890123$^67800
*5555555
sDF564zer""
!!!!!!!!!4!!!!!!!!!!
abcdefghijklmnopq9ss
```

**Not OK:**

*has more or less then 8-20 chars:*

```
a_1+Eff
B41def_hIJ2lmnopq3stt
abCDefghijklmnopqrss5
```

*has whitespace chars:*

```
A_4 e*gg
```

*starts with a number or underscore:*

```
__1+Eff
841DEf_hij2lmnopq3stt
```

*ends with two different chars:*

```
a_1+eFg
b41DEf_hij2lmnopq3st
```

*contains no numbers:*

```
abCDefghijklmnopqrss
abcdef+++dF
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

So far I have this

```
((?m:[^0-9_]^(?=.*[0-9])\S{8,20}$))
```

But I can't seem to figure out the 2 same chars at the end?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will work in most regex flavors (PCRE, Python, PHP, JavaScript):

```
/^(?=\S{8,20}$)(?=\D*\d)(?![0-9_]).{6,18}?(.)\1$/i
```

[**Demo with unit tests against your sample cases**](https://regex101.com/r/eJ4rW1/4)

Explanation:

- `/` delimiter
- `^` start of string
- `(?=\S{8,20}$)` followed by 8-20 non-whitespace characters
- `(?=\D*\d)` contains a digit
- `(?![0-9_])` can't start with a number or underscore
- `.{6,18}?` non-greedy character match (moves us from the start of the string toward the end)
- `(.)\1` match any character, followed by the same character again
- `$` end of the string
- `/` delimiter
- `i` flag: case-insensitive (required to see `Gg`, for example, as the same character twice)

Comment: thx for your answer. it has to be a .NET regex, but i will work my way arround it. Niels

Answer (score 1):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
^(?=.*\d)[\D\S]\S{5,17}(\S)\1$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bD0TcaW-vtsiwTLa)

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gX2oG2/1)

Comment: This fails; it will match, for example, `5bCDefghijklmnopqrss`